# Actualización de datos cuando la app está cerrada swift

Tags: firebase, ios, swift

Buen día, mi pregunta, hay alguna manera de agarrar la información que llega de la notificación de firebase cuando la app está cerrada de segundo plano?

logré capturarla y guardarla en la siguiente función

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
```

cuando se está en 2do plano y en ejecución, pero no logro hacerlo cuando está cerrada

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma de despertar a la app y que esta reciba data y puedas guardar esta data, vas a tener solo 30 segundos para este proceso de guardado, por lo tanto no puede ser data grande.

Para esto el push que envías debe tener 'content-available:1'

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

lo que debes hacer es que firebase envíe ese parámetro.

Aquí tienes la documentación de apple respecto a este tema: [Background Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app?language=objc)